# php-pam for php7.3 and php7.4 in parallel?

Tags: debian, php, pam

I have both php7.4 and php7.3 in use on my Debian 10 (buster) system as I have dependencies on both. (From https://deb.sury.org/ php apt repos.)
But the pam module is not available as a version-specific debian package (like 'php7.4-pam') but only as a general 'php-pam'.

This module is installed and it ends up in /usr/lib/php/20180731, which is the directory for php7.3.
But the service depending on php7.4 is complaining that it's missing the pam.so module in folder /usr/lib/php/20190902, which is the php7.4 folder.

A quick experiment with a symlink shows that of course the pam versions are not interchangeable and need to be compiled against their respective php version.

How do I install the php-pam module for php7.4 in parallel to the existing one for php7.3?